# why do get a an output of 1 with the following code?

Tags: python-3.x

I am new to python and trying things out.  This following code i wrote returned a value of 1 when I was testing it out.  Can anyone explain why?

```
def cube(x):
    return x < 2 + x

result = (cube(5) ** 3)
print(result)
```

Comment: `return x < 2 + x` for x = 5 gives you `True`, as 5 < 2 + 5. Then calling `cube(5) ** 3` a silent type-conversion is performed (`True` --> integer `1`), which allows to compute the statement `1 ** 3`, which gives one cubed, so you get `1` printed.

Comment: does it help if i write `def cube(x): return (bool) (x < (2 + x))`  ?

Comment: Can you describe in your own words what you expect `x < 2 + x` to mean?

Answer (score 2):

Your function

```
def cube(x):
    return x < 2 + x
```

returns `x < 2 + x`.

`x < 2 + x` checks whether `x` is smaller than `2 + x`, and returns `true` when it is. If you put that into your `result` calculation, you have:

```
result = ( true ** 3 )
```

When you apply mathematical operators to boolean values, they're converted to `1` if `true` and `0` if `false`. So your `result` calculation is equivalent to

```
result = ( 1 ** 3 )
```

which is 1.